# Problemas al acceder a una funcion dentro de una funcion estatica clases

Tags: javascript, poo

Me gustaría poder acceder a la función calcular que esta dentro de una función estática que esta dentro de una clase, es un ejercicio simple, tal ves se pueda hacer con bind pero no tengo idea.

```
class A {
  
  array;
  
  static iniciarArray(dato){
    this.array = dato;
  }
  
  calcular(){
    console.log("entro en calcular")
  }
  
  static pregunta(){
    if(this.array){
      console.log(this.calcular())
    }
   
  }
}

const main = () =>{
  A.iniciarArray(["nombre",1])
  A.pregunta();
  
}

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es lo que sucede, tu tienes algo asi

```
class A {
  
  array;
  
  static iniciarArray(dato){
    
  }
  
  calcular(){
    
  }
  
  static pregunta(){
   
  }
}
```

pero en realidad javascript tiene algo de esta forma

```
function ES5 () {
  
  constructor (arr) {

    this.array =arr;
  }

  calcular () {}

}

ES5.prototype.pregunta = function () {
  
}
ES5.prototype.iniciarArray = function () {
  
}
```

si estas un poco familiarizado con el context execution sabras que las function declarations crean su propio contexto y el contexto es bajo prototype por lo que tu instancia no tiene acceso a la function pregunta porque tienen dos contextos distintos.

Para poder ejecutar calcular dentro de pregunta el contexto de calcular debe de estar accesible dentro del contexto de prototype, como se hace eso, crea una instancia de adentro de preguntar.

```js
class A {
  ....
  
  calcular (param) {
     //... codigo
  }
}

A.preguntar (algunValor) {
  return new A().calcular(algunValor)
}
```

existe algo que se hacen llamar los tipos algebraicos el core de la programación functional los puedes buscar con el nombre de monads o functors

Answer (score 1):

No puedes usar el `this` en un contexto `static`. Tendrías que colocar como estático al metodo `calcular()`.

```js
class A {
  
  array;
  
  static iniciarArray(dato){
    A.array = dato;
  }
  
  static calcular(){
    console.log("entro en calcular")
  }
  
  static pregunta(){
    if(A.array){
      console.log(A.calcular())
    }
   
  }
}

const main = () =>{
  A.iniciarArray(["nombre",1])
  A.pregunta();
  
}

main()
```